# Wordpress - Click an attachment image to view next image

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, adsense, photo-gallery

I want to make my attachment image clickable so that click event move user to next image attachment page. I don't want any lightbox gallery i just wanna do it in a normal way. I want to show every image of gallery on separate page for better adsense optimization. Is there an easy way to do it ? ? 
If You Can Please Help..

Answer (score 0):

With this plugin you can have gallery pagination
http://wordpress.org/plugins/file-gallery/

Comment: How to paginate gallery images. ?? Documents are not providing clear picture.